# Error connecting to SQL server after upload

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection

I know this sounds similar to many questions already asked, but those were answered mainly by reconfiguring the connection string. In my case, the scenario is a bit different.

I'm connecting to a remote server, and everything works fine on my local PC. I can access it via SQL Server Management Studio Express, and the application itself connects without problem. After I upload everything, without changing the connection string, I get the famous `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server` error.

The connection string is like:

```
<add name="barConnStr" 
     connectionString = "Persist Security Info=False;
                         Data Source=XX.XXX.X.XXX\SQLDBG;
                         Initial Catalog=FGE;
                         User Id=uid;
                         Password=pass" 
     providerName     = "System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Anyone got an idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Where do you upload it? Is it possible that the location you upload your code has a firewall or restricted access to the network?

Comment: It's a hosting company server, so I guess there's no firewall there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to disable the firewall in both servers and see if it works if so you need to add rules to the firewall

Comment: The server I upload the app to is a hosting company server, so I guess it has no firewall, and the fact that I'm able to connect to DB server from my local PC means that there probably isn't one on that server also.

Comment: are you using the same credentials when logging from your PC and from the app?

Comment: @Juliusz Any way I can check that? As much as I know they are the same.

Comment: is your server is windows server?

Comment: Yes, Windows, ASP.net hosting server.

Comment: in your connection string do you use IP or server name?

Comment: try to read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

Comment: I accepted the answer, the comments were helpful, but the server administrator solved the problem.